# How to make list inside div expand after content in list

Tags: html, css

I'm quite annoyed by allways manualy enter fixed width till div depending on how many letters a `li` tag contains

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact information example</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

div{
background:red;
}
div ul li{
float:left;
}
```

This div will have same height as the list itself however the width will be 0. My problem is that i have to manualy fill in static values in the css file to adjust the div after `li` This might be okey in some situations but when your navigation is dynamicly generated its quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your div:

```
display: inline-block;
```

and that's it :)

here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RGeWL/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
div {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

this will cause the parent `div` to contain all the floated child elements (block formatting context).

The `div` will have the height of the of the floated elements instead of collpasing to 0 due to no content in normal flow.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Note: Using `display: inline-block` will cause the `div` to have a shrink-to-fit width based on the width of the floated child elements.

Comment: This would give the DIV (as you stated) the width of the parent, I assume the OP wants the width of it's content.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried that and it didn't shrink.

Comment: overflow wraps floatting content, it just triggers layout and is often usefull. here half of the job is done, you need to make it shrink to content. display:inline-block, table or inline-table , as float will do, all will trigger layout and will shrink on content.